# Fluid interacting with objects

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

What is the correct setting for fluid interacting with objects in the scene. What needs change in the obstacle panel in the fluid simulator. My settings right now are the object has the obstacle fluid settings applied to it and in the panel I have the VOLUME INITIALIZATION set to BOTH with a PARTIAL SLIP and NO IMPACT FACTOR. Is this correct?

Comment: More information and some pictures would be nice...

Answer (score 1):

You can have a quick "basic" fluid simulation in this way:

1. open a default file (cube),
2. select the cube
3. press <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, type "quick",
4. the list will show some "quick" setups
5. choose "quick fluid".

[image]

6. You'll get a ready-to-go basic fluid simulation with a "fluid cube" ready to splash into a bigger cubic domain (select wireframe mode to see inside the domain)

[image]

7. now, add another simple object below the "fluid cube", like a sphere. Be sure that all the sphere lies inside the cubic domain, though.

[image]

[image]

8. add "fluid" to the sphere through its physics property tab, and set the "type" to "obstacle".

[image]

9. now select the domain, and bake the simulation

[image]

10. once finished backing, playback the animation, the "fluid cube" will splash onto the sphere, interacting with it and then will go to the bottom of the domain

(moved the camera to see the fluid covering the sphere, from bottom view)

[image]

Then you can change this example to fit your needs.